# Grub4dos UEFI error - Cannot mount selected partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, uefi, grub4dos

I am using Grub4dos for UEFI (release 2023-10-16) to boot ISO files in partition named "STORING". The type of HDD is GPT as in the below picture

[image: Disks]

The file MENU.LST is

[image: menu.lst]

Grub4dos for UEFI cannot boot into ISO files. The message is "CANNOT MOUNT SELECTED PARTITION" as in the below picture

[image]

Please help me to change "MENU.LST" to get it to boot properly.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: If _"Grub4dos for UEFI cannot boot into ISO files"_ then what sort of solution exactly are you hoping for?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. When I install Grub4dos into USB drive, It boot successfully into ISO files. but if when I install Grub4dos into HDD drive, it is failed to boot

Comment: I think _you_ misunderstand how these things work. The ISO file contains a filesystem image which you can write onto a raw partition on a USB drive _or_ a regular hard drive. What you have instead of that is an NTFS file system (this is what the ISO image would replace) which happens to contain some ISO files. It's kind of like you tried to open a Word document _containing_ an image in a drawing program.

Comment: There are 2 versions of GRUB4DOS. GRUB4DOS legacy and GRUB4DOS UEFI. I try GRUB4DOS legacy for my USB drive (NTFS file system) with same MENU.LST and it boot successfully ISO file. But GRUB4DOS UEFI the result is failed